# Can I keep syntastic from opening the Location List?

Tags: vim, syntastic

I work in a lot of legacy files that are huge and previous devs didn't always follow proper styles, so syntastic gives me a ton of linting errors that I don't care about right now. I put syntastc into passive mode and manually check the file then close the location list, which works great. But, after I've manually checked it, every time I :w, the location list opens back up and shows the previous errors. I can't figure out a way to keep this from happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Syntastic is not a mind reader.  For this reason, you're supposed to run `:SyntasticReset` to let it know you want it to shut up, rather than just close the error window.

Comment: thanks, I hadn't heard of the function. I guess I'll have to run that after checking so everything stays closed until I want it.

Comment: @lcd047: why would it open the location list in passive mode?

Comment: @eugeney Because `BufEnter` triggers a notification refresh, so that the error window gets updated when you switch buffers..

Comment: @lcd047 That's good to know, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the [`syntastic_mode_map`](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt) option set in your `.vimrc`? This may influence how Syntastic does automatic checking:

> In passive mode, automatic checks are still done for filetypes in the
>   "active_filetypes" array (and "passive_filetypes" is ignored). In
>   active mode, automatic checks are not done for any filetypes in the
>   "passive_filetypes" array ("active_filetypes" is ignored).

Comment: Yeah, I have the mode map set to passive in my vimrc, which turned off the auto checking for me. But the location list opens every time I save or move into that buffer from another buffer, such as a split.

Answer (score 11):

One can prevent the location list from opening using `syntastic_auto_loc_list=0`. A pretty unobtrusive setup is:

```
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:syntastic_auto_jump = 0
```

Combined with highlighting to see the errors better:

```
hi SpellBad term=reverse ctermbg=darkgreen
```